# Connecting adjectives in Japanese

Tags: adjectives, conjunctions

Till now I have learnt that you connect adjectives with te-form. However, I saw this information given on a website-
Here is an exception. You can connect adjectives without using the te-form if two adjectives are different categories. That is to say, adjectives are categorized into three groups: the first is “Amount” and “Kind,” e.g. “[多]{おお}い: many” and “various: いろんな.” The second is “Subjective Judgments,” e.g. “[好]{す}き: to like” and “いい: good.” The third is “Attributes,” e.g. “[大]{おお}きい: big” and “[新]{あたら}しい: new.” When you use two adjectives from different groups, you can directly connect them.

> これが[私]{わたし}の[好]{す}きな[甘]{あま}いケーキ（だ / です）。
>
> This is the sweet cake that I like.

> いろんな[古]{ふる}い[車]{くるま}が（ある / あります）。
>
> There are various old cars.

In these sentences, is the original adjective form remaining because you have a noun at the end of the sentence? For example, if I were to place the noun at the start of the sentence would the sentence appear as follows-
このケーキはすきで甘いです。

When we are writing 好きな甘いケーキ, we are actually using　好きな to describe only cake right?

Comment: I may be misreading your question, but there's always ambiguity about the modifying relationship. In English version too, grammatically speaking, it is ambiguous whether *that I like* describes *sweet cake* or just *cake*.

Answer (score 2):

I would rather put it this way. They retain their noun-modifying forms because they modify the noun phrases 甘いケーキ and 古い車.

In the first example 甘い modifies ケーキ to form the noun phrase 甘いケーキ first. This binding is stronger than that between 好きな and ケーキ because sweetness is a more integral "attribute" of the cake which you like. Before 私の好きな甘いケーキ was put into that noun-modifying structure, it would have been a statement like:

> 私はこの［甘いケーキ］が好きです。

You take out 甘いケーキ and modify it with the rest of the statement, and you get:

> ［私の／が好きな］［甘いケーキ］

While このケーキは好きで甘いです is not grammatically wrong, it doesn't sound natural unless it's said in specific contexts that make it natural. If you want to say that you like the cake and that the cake is sweet as two independent facts in one sentence, you would have to say something like:

> 私はこのケーキが好きで、（このケーキは）甘いです。

The first part is about your preference and the second is about the cake's properties.

From this you can get the following noun phrase.

> ［私が好きで、甘い］［ケーキ］

So it depends on whether you see the two adjectives in a parallel relationship or in a nested relationship.

Comment: So can I write- このケーキは私が好きで甘いです。

Comment: So doesn't it boil down to whether we use これ or この？